# Exception got while sending email

Tags: asp.net

i copy that code 
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

```
        mail.To.Add(model.To);

        mail.From = new MailAddress("sheikh.abm@gmail.com");


        mail.Subject = model.Subject ;

        mail.Body = model.Message;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost:");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = "localhost:";
        client.Port = 25;

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(model.To, "abc");

        client.Credentials = credentials;

        try
        {
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch
        {



        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

the exception i got is "SSL must not be enabled for pickup-directory delivery methods"
.

Comment: Well, what happens when you turn off SSL?

Comment: oddly enough, i googled just your error message and look what i got: http://metalthought.blogspot.com/2009/03/ssl-must-not-be-enabled-for-pickup.html

Comment: dude i copy that code also i got same exception